# Joining tables and selecting foreign key where all rows meet condition in first table

Tags: mysql, sql, compare, case

I have 2 tables

Accounts

```
ID  | Deleted? |  Type
1   |     0    |   Father
2   |     0    |   Son
3   |     1    |   Son
4   |     1    |   Son
5   |     0    |   Father
6   |     0    |   Father
7   |     1    |   Son
8   |     0    |   Son
9   |     0    |   Father
10  |     1    |   Son
```

Rel_Accounts

```
ID  | SON | FATHER 
 1  |  4  |   6
 2  |  3  |   6
 3  |  2  |   5
 4  |  4  |   1
 5  |  7  |   1
 6  |  8  |   9
 7  |  10 |   9
```

I want to select only the  active (deleted =0) fathers IDs who do have SONs Deleted = 1:

```
FATHERS
6
1
```

How do you get these records when FATHER = 0 but all his SONs Deleted = 1?

I have tried the following but it did not work:

```
SELECT A.ID,
    case when A.DELETED = 0
    THEN (SELECT AH.SONS FROM ACCOUNTS_REL AH WHERE AH.FATHER = A.ID AND A.DELETED = 1)
    END
FROM ACCOUNTS A 
WHERE A.TYPE = 'Father'
```

The expected results are 1 and 6 because they are active fathers and *all* of their sons are deleted.

Comment: have u attempted anything?

Comment: I added to the description...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want all active father which all of his sons has deleted this equal to say all active fathers which has sons but no active son, then try below:

```
select distinct rc.father
    from accounts a 
    join rel_accounts rc on a.id=rc.father
where a.deleted=0 
      and rc.father not in 
     (select qrc.father
             from accounts qa 
             join rel_accounts qrc on qa.id=qrc.father
      where qa.deleted=0 
            and qrc.son in 
           (select qracc.son
                   from rel_accounts qracc 
                   join accounts qacc on qracc.son=qacc.id
                   where qacc.deleted=0))
order by father desc
```

see the [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edf94/3)

Comment: This works perfectly! You earn a plus, cause' at the same time this one pulls all FATHERS records with **NULL** Sons, I didn't expect that. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where you will need to use multiple joins to create the data set you want.  If I am understanding you correctly, you want to filter out account records that are deleted from the result set, then return only rows representing fathers that have a son.  Something like this should suffice:

```
Select distinct F.id from accounts F
join rel_accounts R on R.father=F.id
join accounts S on S.id=R.son
where F.deleted=0 and S.deleted=0;
```

The joins themselves do the work of filtering out results you don't want, then you can simply exclude the deleted rows from the result set.

Someone else might be able to throw together a slightly cleaner version for you.

Answer (score 0):

As I always suggest, break this down into pieces and put them back together.

Start by getting a list of active fathers:

```
SELECT id
FROM accounts
WHERE deleted = 0 AND type = 'Father';
```

It's also important to know the inactive sons:

```
SELECT id
FROM accounts
WHERE deleted = 1 AND type = 'Son'
```

Now, just pull from the rel_accounts table where father is IN the first query, and son is IN the second query:

```
SELECT *
FROM rel_accounts
WHERE father IN(
  SELECT id
  FROM accounts
  WHERE deleted = 0 AND type = 'Father')
 AND son IN(
   SELECT id
   FROM accounts
   WHERE deleted = 1 AND type = 'Son');
```

**EDIT** I thought this was the solution, but after testing I realized this doesn't check that *every* son has been deleted. To do that, I first got the number of sons each father had:

```
SELECT father, COUNT(*) AS numSons
FROM rel_accounts
GROUP BY father;
```

I used the same approach to get the number of deleted sons per each active father:

```
SELECT father, COUNT(*) AS numDeletedSons
FROM rel_accounts
WHERE father IN(
  SELECT id
  FROM accounts
  WHERE deleted = 0 AND type = 'Father')
 AND son IN(
   SELECT id
   FROM accounts
   WHERE deleted = 1 AND type = 'Son')
GROUP BY father;
```

And then I used a join to my last subquery. If the father has the same number of deleted sons as total sons, they should be included:

```
SELECT a.father
FROM(
  SELECT father, COUNT(*) AS numDeletedSons
  FROM rel_accounts
  WHERE father IN(
    SELECT id
    FROM accounts
    WHERE deleted = 0 AND type = 'Father')
  AND son IN(
    SELECT id
    FROM accounts
    WHERE deleted = 1 AND type = 'Son')
  GROUP BY father) a
JOIN(
  SELECT father, COUNT(*) AS numSons
  FROM rel_accounts
  GROUP BY father) b ON b.father = a.father AND b.numSons = a.numDeletedSons;
```

I got your expected results in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d59d2/7).

Comment: Thanks for break your answer in parts, I learned a lot. Your level of awesomeness is breaking limits. :) I didn't know my Rel_Accounts table have NULL values (Fathers actives without sons) @Farhang Amary 'Ferhęg's query resolve that. Your query pulls all the records from original problem. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @axor glad I could help. You never mentioned null sons in your problem, so I didn't think it was a consideration.